# Line-height of text in wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, text

I manage a few different wordpress sites with various themes, plugins, and other specificities. One thing that I have noticed is that for some of these sites, the line-height for text in the admin area is very cramped, like as if there was some kind of CSS error occurring. Whereas for other sites, the equivalent text is displayed with a nice, more-or-less standard line height of about 1.5 or so. Is there some way to get the sites that are not displaying this standard line-height to do so?

You can see in the two images here what I mean — the first is without the standard line-height, the second is with it. Any help appreciated!

— — — — —

(Edit to clarify: I do not need to figure out what CSS hack to use to get the text to display properly — ideally I want to figure out what is *not* loading that is causing this error to occur.)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS you will need:

```
* {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

You could add this at "Customize" -> "Additional CSS" but notice that this will affect all elements because of the "*". You can see more selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), for example if you only want it to affect the content of posts, you would do:

```
.entry-content {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

You can add "!important" to ignore the css hierarchy like so:

```
.entry-content {
  line-height: 1.6 !important;
}
```

You can see the ids and classes of certain elements by using the element inspector of your browser e.g. "f12" on firefox, clicking on the button shown in the image below and then clicking on the element of the page you are interested in.

[image]

If you are only interested in the wp-admin page, you could use the hook below in your plugin code:

```php
add_action( 'admin_head', 'asd_set_custom_line_height' );
function asd_set_custom_line_height(){
    echo "
    <style type='text/css'>
    * {
        line-height: 1.6;
    }
    </style>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, what you describe is not really exactly what I’m trying to answer. I want to know _why_ the text in the main post field is getting ‘crunched’ in some cases, while remaining normally formatted in others. It seems like it could be a problem where something that _should_ load in `wp-admin` is now _not_ loading. So, if at all possible, I’d like to understand what to do with the setup as it is now, rather than try to add any extra CSS as a quick-hack fix. Regardless, thanks for your suggestions — if there is not other way to fix it, I may go with this approach!

Comment: @Tom did you try using the f12 dev tools? you will find the CSS responsible for the line height and then hopefully trace it back to what causes that CSS to be there. Asking here what causes the CSS to be there in "sites with various themes, plugins, and other specificities" is extremely vague. Best of luck though.